# How to Compare Max(Count(*)) value without using SubQuery in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I want to compare `count(*)` value with `max(count(*))` value without using whole query in subquery block. The related example is shown below. Please suggest me a shortest and best way to achieve the same result?

```
select ee.LocationName
from Employees ee
inner join EmployeeActivities ea on ee.Username = ea.Username
where ea.Activity = 'Hospital'
group by LocationName
having count(*) =
(
    select max(VisitCount) 
    from (select LocationName, count(*) as VisitCount 
    from Employees e
    inner join EmployeeActivities ea on e.Username = ea.Username
    where ea.Activity = 'Hospital'
    group by e.LocationName) as a
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
select top 1 with ties ee.LocationName
from Employees ee
inner join EmployeeActivities ea on ee.Username = ea.Username
where ea.Activity = 'Hospital'
group by LocationName
order by count(*) desc
```

Just order descending by count and select top ones(`with ties` will select all groups with max count).

Comment: Thank you. You made my day! :)